# Getting the type of Interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Currently, I am learning Java on Hyperskill, there is one question that I need help and clarification.

The link for this question is [here](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2589).

You need to implement method `getComparatorType(Class)` in `ComparatorInspector` class. The method should examine provided class and return Type object that corresponds to the type parameter that parameterizes Comparable interface the class implements. Consider the example:

```java
class MyInt implements Comparable<Integer> {
    // Implementation omitted 
}

// Method to implement
Type type = ComparatorInspector.getComparatorType(MyInt.class);

System.out.println(type.getTypeName());
// prints: java.lang.Integer since MyInt implements Comparable with Integer parameter type
```

The method should:

1. Return type parameter for Comparable interface class implements
2. Return null if Comparable interface does not have type parameter
3. Should not produce compile-time warnings
4. Compile-time error should arise if class not implementing Comparable is provided as input value
5. No 'rawtype' warnings should remain or be suppressed
6. Method getComparatorType should be generic
   You are free to correct method's type signature if needed.

My code so far:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<?>> Type getComparatorType(Class<T> clazz) {
        // Add implementation
        // Print type name
        if (clazz.getGenericInterfaces().length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        Type t = null;
        Type[] types = clazz.getGenericInterfaces();
        for (Type type : types) {
            if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                t = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
```

I think the only problem I have here is the parameter type in the method signature. As far as I understand, the type in the method signature will be used in the parameter of this method and this type T should extend Comparable. But there is a flaw somewhere in the method signature, hope someone can help. I'm much appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me. The only issue I see is that when looping over the interfaces, you're not checking whether you actually found the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Can you give it a try on HyperSkill, the test cases are kind of mysterious. I have stuck with this for a while. Much appreciate if you can post an answer here.

Comment: Check if `((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType() == Comparator.class`. And things can get complicated if the interface is not implemented directly.

Comment: Yeah, it can be implemented indirectly I think so.

Comment: Thank you man, this check works! This problem has been solved.

Comment: First of all, you should not confuse `Comparable` and `Comparator`. Further note, both, subclassing and extending the interface, can break this simple approach. For some classes, it is even impossible to get the actual type parameter.